# Nested queries, both using NOT IN() - how does this work?

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
SELECT S.sname
FROM Sailors S
WHERE S.sid NOT IN (SELECT R.sid
        FROM Reserves R
        WHERE R.bid NOT IN (SELECT B.bid    
        FROM Boats B
        WHERE B.color='red'))
```

Trying to understanding this. How does this query find the names of sailors who reserved only red boats and sailors that do not reserve any boat at all. How does a `NOT IN` nested within another `NOT IN` work?

Comment: what is you question sir?

Comment: Inner most query will fetch all the red color boats then inner query will fetch all the reserved boats among red color boats then outer query will fetch all the sailors who have reserved the red color boats.

Answer (score 0):

Your query shows the `sailors` that are not in `reserves` with a boat that is not `red`.

You can rewrite it in this way:

```
SELECT S.sname
FROM Sailors S
WHERE S.sid NOT IN (SELECT R.sid
        FROM Reserves R
        WHERE R.bid IN (SELECT B.bid    
        FROM Boats B
        WHERE B.color <> 'red'))
```

Comment: Could you try with my query and see if that produces the same output?

Comment: Yup it have the same output

Answer (score 0):

This query tries to exclude all the sailors who reserved a boat with any color other than red. I believe we can use `JOIN` to make it more readable, e.g.:

```
SELECT s.name
FROM sailors s LEFT JOIN reserves r ON s.sid = r.sid
JOIN boats b on r.bid = b.bid
WHERE b.color = 'Red'
GROUP BY s.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(b.color)) <= 1;
```

Comment: You probably exclude the sailors that don't appear in reserves at all.

Comment: @KennyQuahKokSiong don't know what these screen shots mean to be honest.

Comment: Those are the tables and the output of the queries need someone to explain how a not in within a not in works